# Simple join of two Data Frames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames in a Python program using Pandas.
I am new to Pandas.

Each one has a number of columns and rows - the first is similar to:

```
   calc_1  calc_2 calc_3
0  34.3   43.1  42.0
2  3.0    4.0   5.0
3  6.1    6.1   6.2
4  4.2    4.3   4.5
```

The second is similar to:

```
   gender  age 
0  M      25
2  M      27
3  M      27
4  F      36
```

For every integer row index there is a corresponding entry in the second data frame. I would like to join them into a resulting data frame where the row indices are equal, such as an inner join in SQL.

I can't seem to get this correct. Append results in 2 x the number of rows I should have. The info is coming in from a CSV.

```
   calc_1  calc_2 calc_3  gender age
0  34.3   43.1  42.0      M      25
2  3.0    4.0   5.0       M      27
3  6.1    6.1   6.2       M      27
4  4.2    4.3   4.5       F      36
```

I would like to preserve the column order if possible when joining.

**EDIT:**

I can't seem to use merge because the integer index has no name

```
 pd.merge(df1, df2, on='?????', how='inner')
```

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')` would work

Answer (score 5):

Use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) and pass `axis=1` to concatenate column-wise:

```
In [37]:

pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1)
Out[37]:
   calc_1  calc_2  calc_3 gender  age
0    34.3    43.1    42.0      M   25
2     3.0     4.0     5.0      M   27
3     6.1     6.1     6.2      M   27
4     4.2     4.3     4.5      F   36
```

or [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join):

```
In [38]:

df.join(df1)
Out[38]:
   calc_1  calc_2  calc_3 gender  age
0    34.3    43.1    42.0      M   25
2     3.0     4.0     5.0      M   27
3     6.1     6.1     6.2      M   27
4     4.2     4.3     4.5      F   36
```

Or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) and set `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`:

```
In [41]:

df.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[41]:
   calc_1  calc_2  calc_3 gender  age
0    34.3    43.1    42.0      M   25
2     3.0     4.0     5.0      M   27
3     6.1     6.1     6.2      M   27
4     4.2     4.3     4.5      F   36
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping it would be this simple. Nice comprehensive answer.

Comment: The above works in this case because the indices match, it would be more complicated if it didn't