# Joining two dataframes in pandas - understanding the different join types?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I would like to join, but I'm getting confused as to how to do so, or whether this requires a join at all. 
My first dataframe has a column 'Death City' which is a string name of a city that is not unique (ie it can occur many times in the data set). I have another data set which has only two columns, 'City' and 'Zip Code', which has a list of cities and their corresponding zip code. I want to append a column to the first dataframe that is the corresponding zip code to the 'Death City'. What's the best way to accomplish this? I tried doing

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Death City', right_on='City', how='outer')
```

but it's returning a much bigger data frame. I just want the values of df1 with the zip code appended. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple join of two Data Frames in Pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348479/simple-join-of-two-data-frames-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need left join in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Death City', right_on='City', how='left')
```

The best is it explained in [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).

Comment: this still seems to be returning a dataframe that is size(df1) x size(df2) ?

Comment: Then problem is duplicates in `df2` in column `City`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [Series.map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) if you want to add only one column, otherwise use [pd.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) :

```
df1['Zip Code'] = df1['Death City'].map(df2.set_index('City')['Zip Code'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Death City' : pd.Series(['city1', 'city1', 'city2','city3']),
 'column2' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.])}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
d = {'city' : pd.Series(['city1', 'city2','city3','city4']),
 'zipcode' : pd.Series([11111,2222, 3333., 44444])}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

So In this example: df1 has 3 unique Death City and 4 rows and a second column. df2 has 4 cities and 4 zipcodes.

```
df1a=df1.drop_duplicates(['Death City'])
```

If you want to get unique "death city"s , zipcode combinations then first drop duplicates from df1 so that you have 3 unique rows

```
df_merged=pd.merge(df1a,df2,left_on='Death City',right_on='city')
```

then left join df2 to df1 on df1.'Death City'=df2.city then remove the redundant city column.

```
df_merged=df_merged[['Death City','zipcode']]
```